# Finding the shortest path in a graph between 2 nodes that goes through a subset of nodes

Tags: performance, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I'm trying to find out an efficient way of finding the shortest path between 2 nodes in a graph with positive edge costs that goes trough a subset of nodes.

More formally:

Given a graph G = (U, V) where U is the set of all nodes in the graph and V is the set of all edges in the graph, a subset of U called U' and a cost function say:

```
    f : UxU -> R+  
    f(x, y) = cost to travel from node x to node y if there exists an edge 
              between node x and node y or 0 otherwise,
```

I have to find the shortest path between a source node and a target node that goes trough all the nodes in U'.

The order in which I visit the nodes in U' doesn't matter and I am allowed to visit a node more than once.

My original idea was to make use of Roy-Floyd algorithm to generate the cost matrix. 
Then, for each permutation of the nodes in U' I would be computing the cost between the source and the target like this: f(source_node, P<sub>1</sub>) + f(P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>) + ... + f(P<sub>k</sub>, target) saving the configuration for the lowest cost and then reconstructing the path.

The complexity for this approach is <s>O(n<sup>3</sup> + k!)</s> O(n<sup>3</sup> + k*k!), where n is the number of nodes in the graph and k the number of nodes in the subset U', which is off limits since I'll have to deal with graphs with maximum n = 2000 nodes out of which maximum n - 2 nodes will be part of the U' subset.

Comment: If it ends up that nobody on SO can provide you a satisfactory answer, you might try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Are the start/end nodes in U? Do you know how large U could be or is it more of theoretical problem?

Comment: @Dan W: Yes, the start/end nodes are part of the U set. U will have at most 2000 elements and U' at most 1998.

Comment: It's `O(n^3 + k*k!)` because the summation for each combination will cost at least `O(k)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generalization of travelling salesman.  If U' == U, you get exactly TSP.

You can use the O(n^2 * 2^n) TSP algorithm, where the exponential factor for full scale TSP (2^n) will reduce to k = |U'|, so you'd get O(n^2 * 2^k).

This has the DP solution to TSP.

http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~mjserna/docencia/algofib/P07/dynprog.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Combine the source node *s* and target node *t* into a single node *z*, and define the node set *U'' := U' union {z}*, with the distances to and from *z* defined by *f(z,x) := f(s,x)* and *f(x,z) := f(x,t)* for all *x in U \ {s, t}*.  Compute shortest paths between all nodes of *U''* and let *f'(x,y)* be the shortest distances, or infinity when there is no appropriate path.  Voila, you now have a travelling salesman problem on the complete directed graph with vertices *U''* and edge weights *f'*.